# Values of Array of struct are nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift

can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong in this case, it goes into case success but it throws a thread The «Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value» Error at the line `self.actions = dataRoles.data` like highlighting **.data**

The JSON looks like

```
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "master",
            "id": 1,
            "inserted_at": "01/02/2021 09:38",
            "name": "Master Admin"
        },
        {
            "code": "user",
            "id": 2,
            "inserted_at": "01/02/2021 09:38",
            "name": "User"
        }
    ],
    "draw": 1,
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 100,
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "recordsTotal": 2,
    "total_pages": 1
}
```

The Struct is

```
import Foundation

struct ListRoles: Codable {
    let companyID: Int!
    let data: [DataRoles]!
    let draw, pageNumber, pageSize, recordsFiltered: Int!
    let recordsTotal, totalPages: Int!
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case companyID = "company_id"
        case data, draw
        case pageNumber = "page_number"
        case pageSize = "page_size"
        case recordsFiltered, recordsTotal
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
    }
}

struct DataRoles: Codable {
    let code: String!
    let id: Int!
    let insertedAt, name: String!
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, id
        case insertedAt = "inserted_at"
        case name
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel that I am working on looks like this

```
class ListRolesViewModel {
    
    weak var delegate: ListRolesViewModelDelegate?
    
    private var action: ListRoles!
    
    private var actions: [DataRoles] = []
    
    func getRoles() {

        guard let accessToken = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "codaxim_access_token") else { return }
        
        self.delegate?.willGetRoles(self)

        Alamofire.request(Url.shared.listAllRoles, method: .get, headers: ["Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    guard let dataRoles = response.data?.decode(for: ListRoles.self) else { return }
                    self.action = dataRoles
                    self.actions = dataRoles.data
                    self.delegate?.didGetRoles(self)
                    print("Success")
                    break
                case .failure:
                    self.delegate?.didFailGetRoles(self)
                    print("Alamofire error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    break
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of ways and none it seems to work, from changing the guard let to if let, adding ! in my struct... If you have any idea what it can be it would help me a lot! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the function `decode(for` called on `data`? And never, never, never, never, never declare struct members in a `Codable` struct as implicit unwrapped optional. **Remove all exclamation marks**. If you want to use the raw data anyway `responseData` (or even `responseDecodable`) is the better response type because it skips the deserialization to dictionary/array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I am using struct members as implicit unwrapped optional because otherwise i am getting Error decoding keyNotFound, No value associated with key Coding Keys...

Comment: In this case use regular optionals `?` but you should fix the error which might indicate a wrong struct hierarchy.